# File-Diff markdown for GitLab

Tags: gitlab, markdown, wiki

is there a way to insert into the GitLab Wiki Module a file diff view like in the commit view?

We write our technical documentation in the GitLab Wiki. Now I want to insert a side-by-side view of an commit of a file. But I don't find the right markdown. I think it should possible, because the view exists in the commit view. So I should use it also in the Wiki.

Thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you mean, but if you go to a wiki page and select "Page History", you can view the diff when clicking on the commit message (not the commit hash). It might default to the inline version, but you can change it to side-by-side

Comment: I want the side-by-side view in my Wiki Content, from a commit of my source code. Not the changes inside the Wiki.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use a screenshot of that page? It might be a simpler solution if it is only going to be used to demonstrate the diff. If it needs more interaction or something fancier, I'll dig deeper.

Comment: I have added a picture. This Diff I want to use in a Wiki-Article. And no I don't want to insert a picture in the Wiki Article. Why? All data are known in the Wiki section! The component is still there and have more functions. That can used into the Wiki